# Calling Angularjs $scope from JavaScript, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property", angular.element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

While I was experimenting with AngularJs and JavaScript, I have tried to call a `$scope` from an outside JavaScript function, but I got the following Error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined" .

Here is my code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    var msg = "new message"
    app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = msg;
    }]);
    function xfunc(){
    var data = angular.
    element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="ctrl"]')).
    scope().message;
    return data
    }
    if (typeof 'xfunc()' !== 'undefined') {
    console.log(xfunc());
    }else{
    console.log("the type of is : ", + typeof 'xfunc()')
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    {{message}}
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I did call `xfunc()` from console and it works fine with no errors.
Please, does anyone know the cause of the error? And is it possible to do it with just pure Javascript and AngularJS, with no third party library? (if possible of course)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it works fine in your console i think you are calling the function before AngularJS has been Bootstrapped. You will have to wait for that, otherwise the object property is not available yet.

Comment: thank you  for your answer, i guess you are totaly right about it, but the problem is how to wait AngularJs to Bootstrap  ?

Comment: Yes it work fine with " setTimeout(function(){ console.log(xfunc()); }, 3000);" but i wonder if there is a more efficient syntaxe ?
PS: thanks a lot !

Comment: I don't think AngularJS has anything like a "after bootstrap" event. But why would you need that anyway? Just run the function from within AngularJS :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the function being called before AngularJs was bootstrapped , so the solution is that i have added :

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    });
```

to load "xfunc()" after the "body" is loaded , so here is my final code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    var msg = "new message"
    app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = msg;
    }]);
    function xfunc(){
    var data = angular.
    element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="ctrl"]')).
    scope().message;
    return data
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    if (typeof 'xfunc()' !== 'undefined') {
    console.log(xfunc());
    }else{
    console.log("the type of is : ", + typeof 'xfunc()')
    }
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    {{message}}
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```